# Intercepting a form submission until callback function received

Tags: javascript, forms, submit

I have a form which I intercept with a `event.preventDefault();` when it is submitted, until the result of a callback function is returned (to get the lat and lng of a postcode). Brief mockup below:

```
$(".form").click(function(){
event.preventDefault();
if(calculateLatLng($(".postcode").val())){
$(this).submit();
}
});
```

However, this form has two submit buttons each determining different methods in the php, how would I allow javascript to identify which button has been clicked to submit the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could explicitly trigger the click event on the desired submit button:

```
$("#submit_1").click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the only way to do this is:

- store which button has been clicked
- get the coordinates
- store the fact, that coordinates have already been fetched
- trigger the click event of the stored button